# Greek language - X Cart

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, web, x-cart

I recently opened up an old website of my own to a different webserver. I uploaded the database, the website files, checked the connections and everything is runnning smoothly. 
The only thing that i can't fix is that the greek language is displayed as

> "????"

. Checked in database and everything is correct, the letters are showing and the coding is utf8. So i ended up thinking it is x-carts problem. What can i try to do? x-cart Version is 4.4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check these points:

1) You database.sql file to import is UTF-8. Greek symbols are readable in a text editor

```
aim-server[~/tmp]$ file -ib database.sql
text/plain; charset=utf-8
aim-server[~/tmp]$ grep ελληνικά database.sql
INSERT INTO `xcart_languages` VALUES ('el','lbl_categories','Categories ελληνικά','Labels');
aim-server[~/tmp]$
```

2) every MySQL variable is UTF-8. Greek symbols are readable in a mysql client

```
[aim_xcart_4_4_1_gold]>show variables like '%colla%';
+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_general_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)

[aim_xcart_4_4_1_gold]>show variables like '%char%';                                                                                                                                          +--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0,00 sec)
[aim_xcart_4_4_1_gold]>select * from xcart_languages where name='lbl_categories';
+------+----------------+-----------------------------+--------+
| code | name           | value                       | topic  |
+------+----------------+-----------------------------+--------+
| en   | lbl_categories | Categories ελληνικά         | Labels |
```

3) Charset is UTF-8 on the ' Main page :: Edit languages :: Greek ' page 
[image]

4) `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");` is added to the include/func/func.db.php file according to 
https://help.x-cart.com/index.php?title=X-Cart:FAQs#How_do_I_set_up_my_X-Cart_to_support_UTF-8.3F

Comment: Ok so, i think you are showing me how to do this using a terminal right? my server has phpmyadmin and i loaded the database table by table because it wouldnt load all at once using the upload menu. I also changed the charset to UTF-8 inside the admin area of xcart and this one did the trick. However, some of the menus are missing, and some characters are not displaying at all. Should i delete and try to reupload the whole thing, making sure i converted the .sql file to UTF-8? Also how can i check your 1st and 2nd points?

Comment: @SotosTzam 
1)phpmyadmin allows you to run any sql queries like a terminal 
https://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/server_sql.php?db=&lang=en&collation_connection=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
<br/>
2)try to clear the xcart_dir/var directory

Comment: I just cant understand how to display the "1)" and "2)" of your first post. I need to go to all tables one by one to see what encoding they are?

Comment: `show table status;` should help you.

Just run these queries 
`show variables like '%colla%'; show variables like '%char%'; show table status;`
here  
https://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/db_sql.php?db=mysql